# JavaFX 1 class CustomNode not found in JavaFX 2

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-1

I try to to remake an app from JavaFX 1 to JavaFX 2. The JavaFX 1 app uses:

```
import javafx.scene.CustomNode;
```

Using this import in JavaFX 2 I receive an error:

> `Cannot find symbol class CustomNode in package javafx.scene`

There is an equivalent in JavaFX 2?

Thanks.

eb

Answer (score 1):

[`Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) is the JavaFX 2 equivalent of a JavaFX 1 [`CustomNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/javafx.scene.CustomNode.html).

A JavaFX 1.3 `CustomNode` was a node with children and no explicit layout (all children needed to be laid out manually by the implementor of the `CustomNode`).

Don't expect JavaFX 1 and JavaFX 2 to be very similar - they are pretty different things.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make the necessary modifications.